# How can I view a patch in Pijul?

Tags: pijul

In [Pijul](https://pijul.org/) how can I see what happened in a patch?
I'm looking for something similar to `git diff <commit> <commit>^`.

I tried [`pijul diff`](https://pijul.org/manual/reference/diff.html) but it seems to only work with branches. And I couldn't get [`pijul log`](https://pijul.org/manual/reference/log.html) to show any details of patches, either.

I suspect what I'm looking for is possible because clicking a patch in [Nest](https://nest.pijul.com/pijul_org/) shows a diff and there is [patch pretty-printing](https://nest.pijul.com/pijul_org/pijul:master/662ad86eb85d3b206204#JuBmQrY5jEw) in libpijul which includes a change list.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking for `pijul change ⟨patch-hash⟩`

---

Edit: `patch` is now called `change`

Comment: This is so awesome! `pijul patch` gives some helpful information I haven't seen in `git diff`: it said when a line was deleted in a subsequent patch.  Still: is there a way to diff two states of the repo? Like if I want to compare a branch today to what it looked like last week or to another branch.

Comment: Is there a way to diff two states of the repo? For example, if I want to compare a branch today to what it looked like 5 PRs ago..

Comment: slightly related question: `pijul patch <patch-hash>` takes a hash, but `pijul credit` only shows patch `internal-id`s. How can I lookup a patch by internal-id?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how to do this with current `pijul`?

```
pijul 1.0.0-beta.2
Pierre-Étienne Meunier <pe@pijul.org>

USAGE:
    pijul <SUBCOMMAND>

OPTIONS:
    -h, --help       Print help information
    -V, --version    Print version information

SUBCOMMANDS:
    add         Adds a path to the tree
    apply       Applies changes to a channel
    archive     Creates an archive of the repository
    change      Shows information about a particular change
    channel     Manages different channels
    clone       Clones an existing pijul repository
    credit      Shows which change last affected each line of the given file(s)
    debug
    diff        Shows difference between two channels/changes
    fork        Create a new channel
    help        Print this message or the help of the given subcommand(s)
    init        Initializes an empty pijul repository
    key         Key generation and management
    list        Lists files tracked by pijul
    log         Show the entire log of changes
    move        Moves a file in the working copy and the tree
    pull        Pulls changes from a remote upstream
    push        Pushes changes to a remote upstream
    record      Creates a new change
    remote      Manages remote repositories
    remove      Removes a file from the tree of tracked files (`pijul record` will then record
                    this as a deletion)
    reset       Resets the working copy to the last recorded change
    tag         Manage tags (create tags, check out a tag)
    unrecord    Unrecords a list of changes
```

Comment: `pijul change` :)